# Вывод данных из таблицы sqlite в телеграм бот aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

Нужно вывести столбец первой строки из таблицы. Как это реализовать?

Таблица:

[image: Таблица]

Мой код:

```
import sqlite3
import random

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

def get_koll(self):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT kol FROM ferma WHERE id = 1").fetchall()                   
            return result
```

```
import config
import logging
import random
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from db import Database

import time
import datetime

#log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#Инициализация бота
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = Database('database.db')
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
if message.text.lower() == "топф":   
        await message.reply(str(db.get_koll))
```

При попытке запуска выдается ошибка в сообщении бота:

```
<bound method Database.get_koll of <db.Database object at 0x00000223E7E1D360>>
```

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется в функции get_koll нужно использовать `fetchone()[0]`

В общем сама функция должна выглядеть так:

```
def get_koll(self):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT kol FROM ferma WHERE id = 1")                  
            return result.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не вызываете ваш метод.
Используйте это в последней строке:

```py
await message.reply(str(db.get_koll()))
```